# How to Convert .SVF file to .GLTF by using Forge in C#/.Net

Tags: c#, .net, autodesk-forge, gltf, forge

I want to convert a .SVF file to .GLTF file. I know by using the node command I can convert the file (https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils). Is there any way to do it in C#/.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the implementation of such conversion is only available in Node.js at the moment.

Comment: Btw. depending on your specific use case there might be alternative ways available. For example, if you don't need *gltf* specifically, you could use the C#/.NET Forge SDK to request geometries from the Model Derivative service in the *obj* format.

Comment: Thanks. I need specific gltf formatted file so I am going to write node.js code for that.